# Trouble converting .py file to .exe due to errors

Tags: python, libs

Im trying to convert .py script into .exe and im getting warnings about lib not found. can someone help? I've looked everywhere. Sorry to say i have no knowledge in using python, my dev is away and i needed to change a few small things in the script

dont know where to start, as im completely new to this.

```
PS C:\Users\User\Documents\Ali\Method\Code\Source code> pyinstaller -F accounts_project.py
58 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.4
58 INFO: Python: 3.7.2
59 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.17134-SP0
61 INFO: wrote C:\Users\User\Documents\Ali\Method\Code\Source code\accounts_project.spec
62 INFO: UPX is not available.
63 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\Ali\\Method\\Code\\Source code',
 'C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\Ali\\Method\\Code\\Source code']
64 INFO: checking Analysis
64 INFO: Building Analysis because Analysis-00.toc is non existent
64 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
65 INFO: Initializing module graph hooks...
67 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
2388 INFO: running Analysis Analysis-00.toc
2390 INFO: Adding Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls to dependent assemblies of final executable
  required by c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe
2436 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe
2476 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-locale-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe
2517 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe
2556 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe
2595 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe
2649 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python37.dll
2688 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-conio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python37.dll
2732 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-locale-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python37.dll
2772 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python37.dll
2811 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python37.dll
2851 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python37.dll
2891 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-filesystem-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python37.dll
2931 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python37.dll
2971 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-environment-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python37.dll
3010 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python37.dll
3049 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-time-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python37.dll
3091 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-process-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python37.dll
3138 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\VCRUNTIME140.dll
3178 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\VCRUNTIME140.dll
3217 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\VCRUNTIME140.dll
3256 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\VCRUNTIME140.dll
3296 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\VCRUNTIME140.dll
3300 INFO: Caching module hooks...
3304 INFO: Analyzing C:\Users\User\Documents\Ali\Method\Code\Source code\accounts_project.py
3429 INFO: Loading module hooks...
3429 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-encodings.py"...
3521 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pydoc.py"...
3522 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-xml.py"...
3705 INFO: Looking for ctypes DLLs
3711 INFO: Analyzing run-time hooks ...
3716 INFO: Looking for dynamic libraries
3757 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\DLLs\_ssl.pyd
3801 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\DLLs\_ssl.pyd
3850 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\DLLs\pyexpat.pyd
3890 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\DLLs\pyexpat.pyd
3929 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\DLLs\pyexpat.pyd
3969 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\DLLs\pyexpat.pyd
4009 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-environment-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\DLLs\pyexpat.pyd
4053 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\DLLs\_hashlib.pyd
4097 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\DLLs\_lzma.pyd
4136 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\DLLs\_lzma.pyd
4184 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\DLLs\_socket.pyd
4231 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\DLLs\_bz2.pyd
4271 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\DLLs\_bz2.pyd
4311 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\DLLs\_bz2.pyd
4350 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\DLLs\_bz2.pyd
4389 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\DLLs\_bz2.pyd
4435 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\DLLs\unicodedata.pyd
4475 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\DLLs\unicodedata.pyd
4514 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\DLLs\unicodedata.pyd
4559 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\DLLs\select.pyd
4605 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\DLLs\_ctypes.pyd
4646 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\DLLs\_ctypes.pyd
4686 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\DLLs\_ctypes.pyd
4752 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\DLLs\libcrypto-1_1.dll
4796 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-utility-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\DLLs\libcrypto-1_1.dll
4836 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\DLLs\libcrypto-1_1.dll
4875 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\DLLs\libcrypto-1_1.dll
4914 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\DLLs\libcrypto-1_1.dll
4954 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\DLLs\libcrypto-1_1.dll
4995 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-environment-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\DLLs\libcrypto-1_1.dll
5035 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-time-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\DLLs\libcrypto-1_1.dll
5074 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\DLLs\libcrypto-1_1.dll
5115 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-filesystem-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\DLLs\libcrypto-1_1.dll
5161 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-utility-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\DLLs\libssl-1_1.dll
5201 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\DLLs\libssl-1_1.dll
5240 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\DLLs\libssl-1_1.dll
5280 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-time-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\DLLs\libssl-1_1.dll
5282 INFO: Looking for eggs
5282 INFO: Using Python library c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python37.dll
5282 INFO: Found binding redirects:
[]
5301 INFO: Warnings written to C:\Users\User\Documents\Ali\Method\Code\Source code\build\accounts_project\warn-accounts_project.txt
5337 INFO: Graph cross-reference written to C:\Users\User\Documents\Ali\Method\Code\Source code\build\accounts_project\xref-accounts_project.html
5354 INFO: checking PYZ
5355 INFO: Building PYZ because PYZ-00.toc is non existent
5355 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) C:\Users\User\Documents\Ali\Method\Code\Source code\build\accounts_project\PYZ-00.pyz
5717 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) C:\Users\User\Documents\Ali\Method\Code\Source code\build\accounts_project\PYZ-00.pyz completed successfully.
5725 INFO: checking PKG
5725 INFO: Building PKG because PKG-00.toc is non existent
5725 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg
6802 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg completed successfully.
6805 INFO: Bootloader c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\bootloader\Windows-32bit\run.exe
6805 INFO: checking EXE
6805 INFO: Building EXE because EXE-00.toc is non existent
6805 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc
6806 INFO: Appending archive to EXE C:\Users\User\Documents\Ali\Method\Code\Source code\dist\accounts_project.exe
6836 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc completed successfully.
```

Comment: I get pages and pages of those warnings. Note that they are `WARNINGS`, not errors. From your log, it looks like it successfully created the `EXE`. The result should be `C:\Users\User\Documents\Ali\Method\Code\Source code\dist\accounts_project.exe`.

Comment: Have you tried using some other library like cx_Freeze?

Comment: No, can you advise how i would go about doing that?

Comment: @JohnAnderson the .exe file gives an error which opens and closes which is why i think he warnings play a part?

Comment: Can you run the `.exe` in a terminal (as opposed to double clicking the icon). That way you might see some error messages.

Comment: @JohnAnderson - Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "accounts_project.py", line 17, in <module>
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "personal\filing.py", line 10, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'uis' from 'personal' (C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI80442\personal\__init__.pyc)

Comment: So it looks like line 17 in `accounts_project.py` is something like `from personal import uis`. Is `uis` defined in `personal`?

Comment: yes. thats correct.

Comment: personal is a folder which holds a few of the imports